# How to increase heap size for Android Automation

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso, spoon

I am using spoon runner for executing my test cases developed using Espresso and UI automator. I have around 200 test cases. Most of the time execution is crashed due to out of memory issue. When I checked Android memory monitor, there is only 128 MB of heap space is available. Can we increase this heap space? Or is there any method to clear heap space right after each test completed?

I have tried setting android:largeHeap="true". Can I enable it only for automation?

Comment: I met the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @xhsoldier : Don't use android:largeHeap="true" , try splitting whole test cases functionality wise to different packages and run package wise. You can execute tests by passing package name to spoonrunner. So that, there will be fresh install of application between each runs. And hopefully you can avoid out of memory issue.